# The ways to say something is not necessary

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrase-request

In the sentence I wrote, I am thinking what is the proper construction and tone to relate two clauses of which one is about necessity of something

> 1) Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and **he doesn’t need** to provide the word definitions.
>
> 2) Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and **he is not needed** to provide the word definitions.
>
> 3) Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and **he is not required** to provide the word definitions.
>
> 4) Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and **he is not obliged** to provide the word definitions.
>
> 5) Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and **it is not required that him** to provide the word definitions.
>
> 6) Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and **it is not necessary** to provide the word definitions.

.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for either

> Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and he doesn’t need to provide the word definitions.

or

> Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and he is not obliged to provide the word definitions.

2) and 3) imply that somebody else will provide the word definitions in the end, without the teacher's help.

5) is grammatically incorrect, it should be

> Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words and it is not required that he provides the word definitions.

which conveys the same meaning as 3.

In 6), the second clause looks like it is directed to the pupils, as in:

> Note that the teacher only prepares a list of words. It is not necessary to provide the word definitions, you can just translate them straight away.

Answer (score 1):

The teacher must provide only the list of words, not their definitions.